Чем отличается слово "Заработать" от "Зарабатывать"?
Чем отличается слово Заработать от Зарабатывать?

Заработать - получить что-то(деньги, но не обязательно) за сделанную работу или что-то другое. Зарабатывать - получать определённую сумму денег, за выполнение определённой работы. Заработать - можно сказать, например, про похвалу. Он заработал похвалу у начальника или женщины, он заработал подарок. Также можно с предлогом - он заработал на подарок, он заработал на машину и купил её. А "зарабатывать" почти всегда про зарплату за месяц или другой срок. Сколько ты зарабатываешь? = какая у тебя зарплата(заработная плата) за неделю, месяц и тому подобное. Первый глагол совершенный, второй несов.

Отличие в виде глагола.Совершенный вид указывает на одноразовое действие, несовершенный вид указывает на продолжительные,повторяющиеся действия, которые не доведены до конца.
Первый глагол в вашем примере — совершенный, второй — несовершенный.

Заработать- это уже свершившийся факт. А зарабатывать-это продолжительность действия, т.е. действие в настоящем времени.
